# How can I create a list from a matrix using Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I have the following matrix:

```
   Country Sp 
1 Portugal Cc 
2    Spain Cc 
3   France Cc 
4    Italy Cm
```

If I do:

```
selectInput("country", "Country:", choices=NestingArea$Country)
```

I will get a list of the 4 countries. However, if I want to list just the countries where "Sp==Cc" (Portugal, Spain and France), how should I do it?

Comment: Sounds like a simple subsetting exercise... try `selectInput( "country", "Country:", choices=subset(NestingArea, Sp=='Cc', 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

```r
NestingArea <- data.frame(Country = c("Portugal", "Spain", "France", "Italy"),
                 Sp = c("Cc", "Cc", "Cc", "Cm"))
```

You can get the desired subset of the countries:

```r
NestingArea$Country[NestingArea$Sp == "Cc"]
#> [1] "Portugal" "Spain"    "France"
```

Hence, the solution is:

```r
selectInput("country", "Country:", choices=NestingArea$Country[NestingArea$Sp == "Cc"])
```